# Make negative integers positive within a loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to add integers from a single line separated by spaces and find their absolute value.
There is going to be 5 integers and one of them is negative while the others are positive.
I am trying to find a way to make the current negative value positive in order to find the absolute value of all the numbers. This is what I have so far.

```
read input
# 1, 5, -17, 32, 12
# expected absolute value: 67
absolute_value()
{
    local absolute_value=0

    for nums in $input;
    do
    ((absolute_value += nums))

    done
    echo $absolute_value
}
absolute_value
```

My answer is 33 and the expected answer is 67.
They are of course adding up but since one of the input numbers would be negative, it is giving me the sum and not the absolute value. I'm quite stuck and have been searching around for a bit to find my answer but I just cannot come up with an answer. Bash isn't my strongest language so it might be something that I'm passing over.

Answer (score 3):

Well, how is the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) defined?

```
if [ "$num" -lt 0 ]; then
    num=$((-num))
fi
```

In any case, this:

```
for nums in $input
```

relies on word-splitting and is somewhat ugly. You'll also get interesting effects if someone inputs non-numbers or glob characters. Since you're using Bash, you could avoid the issues with glob characters by reading the values to an array with `read -a`. Also, we can use `[[ var -lt 0 ]]`.

However, doing just that is not good, because arithmetic expansion in Bash is dangerous. It's easy inject commands there via array indexing and command substitution, and the shell will execute them. So, we really need to check that the received values are numbers to begin with.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -a nums
sum=0
for a in "${nums[@]}"; do
    if [[ $a = *[^-0-9]* ]]; then
        echo "invalid number: $a"
        exit 1
    fi 
    if [[ a -lt 0 ]]; then
        sum=$((sum + -a))
    else
        sum=$((sum +  a))
    fi
done
echo "$sum"
```

Note that Bash will interpret numbers starting with `0` and `0x` as octal and hexadecimal, respectively.

---

Or, you know, just do it with a real programming language so you don't need to do everything manually:

```
$ python3 -c 'print(sum(map(lambda x: abs(int(x)), str.split(input()))))'
1 5 -17 32 12
67
```

Comment: I'd add a while loop for the input, I'll add it to my answer below but I think it would be better added o yours, being more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter substitution to remove the minus sign:

```
read input
# 1, 5, -17, 32, 12
# expected absolute value: 67
absolute_value() {
    local absolute_value=0

    for nums in $input; do
      ((absolute_value += ${nums#-} ))
    done
    echo $absolute_value
}

absolute_value
```

To avoid using a for-loop, you can give a try to this:

```
printf "%s\n" ${input/-/} | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

---

I'd use a while loop and an array to control how many inputs could the user do, and keep asking if the input is wrong:

```bsh
declare -a arr
declare -a arr_abs
echo "Enter four numbers:"

while true; do
  read num
  [[ $num =~  ^[^-0-9]$ ]] && echo "Not a number..." && continue
  # keep the original values for any other use
  arr+=($num)
  # create an array with absolute values
  arr_abs+=(${num#-})
  [[ ${#arr[@]} -eq 4 ]] && break
done

absolute_value() {
   sum=$(printf "%s\n" ${arr_abs[@]} | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }')
   echo "The absolute sum is $sum"
}

absolute_value
```